# Civirules intent to select contact with address of one type with the exclusion of another type

Tags: civirules

I have created a type of address labeled "Old" for keeping a record of addresses that are no longer valid for a given contact.

I want to create a Civirules rule for tracking the contacts where the "Old" address is set and no other address is available.

I was hoping the condition "Address is unique" was meaning that there was only one type of address available for a given cntact, but I discovered that this condition is always valid when there is no other contact in the database with the same address.

I would like to know how I can solve my problem: creating a group with all the contacts having an "Old" address and no other address (like "Home", "Work", "Other", etc...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a direct answer but potentially this extension might help you to keep track of old addresses? https://civicrm.org/extensions/former-communication-data

Comment: The use of the extension "Former Communication Data" solves my problem beyond my expectations. So I redesigned my system in order to use this module. Now I will delete the adresses that are no longer valid instead of flagging these as "Old Address". This will protect me from the potential error from a future database administrator to send mail to unexisting old addresses.